# What is the JSON I have to put in Gupshup's Dialogflow JSON?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, gupshup

Since last week there's a new Gupshup functionality in which in order to add a new bot, I can paste in the JSON of the Dialogflow agent.
Where do I get that JSON?
When I export the agent from Dialogflow as ZIP, and unzip it, I have 2 folders (entities + intents) and an 'agent' JSON + 'package' JSON (image below).
[image: Image of files downloaded from Exporting dialogflow agent]

Do I have to take the agent.json and put it in Gupshup?

[image: Gupshup User interface to put the json]

I did that, and deployed it on Telegram to test it (I don't know other way to test it). It's not working. It does not answer anything.
I did the Telegram set up correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Dialogflow Console. Click On The COG icon
   [image: In Dialogflow Console. Click On The COG icon]
2. Click On The Google Project
   [image: Click On The Google Project]
3. Once in Google Console. Click on The Hamburger Icon

[image: Once in Google Console. Click on The Hamburger Icon]

4. Click On IAM & Admin

[image: Click On IAM & Admin]

5. Click On The Service Account

[image: Click On The Service Account]

6. Create A New Service Account

[image: Create A New Service Account]

7. Make Sure To Provide Viewer Access

[image: Make Sure To Provide Viewer Access To The Service Account]

8. After Creation, in the service account list, click on Manage Keys.

[image: After Creation, in the service account list click on Manage Keys.]

9. Add a new Key For that service account

[image: Then Click on Add Key Button]

10. Select Type as JSON

[image: Select Type as JSON]

Then a JSON file will be downloaded to your local machine. Copy-paste the content into the JSON field. Your Dialogflow agent will be linked.

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: It works. I tested it on telegram. Thank you!